# Delegate inside an if else statement c# (UNITY)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just wanted to ask if this proper code

```
if (Info.Instance.localLogin)
    NManager.Instance.SocketServer_SOCKET_ConsoleLoginSuccess += CallBack_SOCKET_ConsoleLoginSuccess;
else
    NManager.Instance.SocketServer_SOCKET_OnlineLoginSuccess += CallBack_SOCKET_OnlineLoginSuccess;
```

Sorry just very new to c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we can conditionally subscribe to a delegate.

Comment: Yes, It's fine.

Comment: Don't forget to unregister with a previously registered delegate as a standard practice. So += and -= operators on delegates means that you subscribe and unsubscribe to an event respectively.

Comment: *`So there's nothing wrong about my code?`* Well, nothing *syntactically* wrong. There might be logic errors, but we can't tell from here. ;)